# How to copy or how to know what kind of widgets the other website are using?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I want to know how to copy widgets from other website. So it will be easy for me to search and place it in my own website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can identify a widget used in a Wordpress site. The only possibility is, look at the source code and see whether there exist any comments that says about that widget.

The better thing that you can do is, based on the widget features and your requirements make a google search.